# Usage of 'represent' to mean 'present again'

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Can the word '*represent*' be used to mean 'present again'? Is the usage in the following sentence correct?

"You cannot *represent* a bounced cheque.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the word you are looking for is:

> [***re-present***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/re-present): *to present again*
>   <sub>*Can be confused with: represent*</sub>